# SQL to Access linked server

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I am trying to add a linked server to a Access database.  I am using the following SQL code to do this.

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver 
@server = 'Test',
@provider = 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
@srvproduct = 'OLE DB Provider for Jet',
@datasrc = '\\srv\public$\CM Database\Data\sysConfig_dat.mdb'
go
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin Test, FALSE, Null, Admin, Null
```

but when i run this...

```
select * from Test...tblProduct
```

i get this error...

> OLE DB provider
>   'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be
>   used for distributed queries because
>   the provider is configured to run in
>   single-threaded apartment mode. what
>   am i doing wrong?

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 on a 32 bit system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out...

The server running SQL Server is a 64Bit machine.  The typical data connectivity component drivers did not work with this machine (ie the download that installs the Microsoft.Jet.OleDB.4.0 as a provider).  I had to download the components for Access 2010 which has a 64Bit option.

[Download from here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d&displaylang=en)

That installs the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 as a provider and I can use the SQL command that BradBenning mentioned in his post.

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: I've SQL Server 2008 on 64Bit machine and Accecc 2007 ... I want  `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`...

Comment: The typical drivers did not work with a 64 bit machine.  I receded to use microsoft ACE OLEDB instead.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the Microsoft ACE OLEDB provider:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
   @server = 'Test'
  ,@provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
  ,@datasrc = '\\srv\public$\CM Database\Data\sysConfig_dat.mdb'
  ,@srvproduct='Access'
GO
```

Comment: that gives me this... '(null)' is an invalid product name.