# Link existing MS-Access database to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, database-link

I have an external application that uses a MS Access database to store its data.
I do not want to touch anything here, because the application works very good for me.

I have now created a own application and now I need the data from the MS Access database in my application. My application uses SQL Server.

Is it possible to sync the existing MS Access database with a new SQL Server database, so that I can query the MS Access database through my SQL Server?

I really don't want a linked table in MS Access because this can not work since I can not change the application that uses the MS Access database, and it would also be great if I don't have to query from the MS Access database.

I really need a tool the reads data from MS Access and writes it into my SQL Server and the other way around so they always have the same data.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You would need to add a `Linked server` to your SQL Server, which references the Access database. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873673/sql-to-access-linked-server

Comment: I tried to add this, but when i expand my server i get the following error: "Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 for linked server"

Comment: Did you consider the 64Bit driver issue?

Comment: As far as i understood is this one working with 64 Bit, is this correct?
Or can you please explain it to me